# No url when downloading PDF

Tags: urls

I've a password protected webpage where uses can download PDFs. When clicking on the Download button, the PDF is uploaded by creating a URL, which works nice but that URL is then visible for everyone.

How can prevent this and get the Download button ask for saving the PDF instead of opening a URL page. Is there a Plugin or another simple trick? I likely miss something.

Thank you for your support, greetings from the Netherlands. Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13839507/1466973 , which involves sending headers with the appropriate values to cause the 'save as' dialog box to appear.

That process will allow you to not provide the URL (which anyone can share), but provide the file (which people can share after they download).